# Not getting the desired output using pocketsphinx

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

My question is i'm using an audio file and converting it into a text

my audio  file contains **"HI HELLO"** but i'm getting the output as
 **FOR SHORT SELLERS TO INDIA WHOM**  I don't know how?

The code which i have used is below.

```
import sys,os


  def decodeSpeech(hmmd,lmdir,dictp,wavfile):
    """
    Decodes a speech file
    """

    try:
        import pocketsphinx as ps
        import sphinxbase

    except:
        print """Pocket sphinx and sphixbase is not installed
        in your system. Please install it with package manager.
        """

    speechRec = ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp)
    wavFile = file(wavfile,'rb')
    wavFile.seek(44)
    speechRec.decode_raw(wavFile)
    result = speechRec.get_hyp()

    return result[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hmdir = "/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/wsj1"
    lmd = "/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/wsj/wlist5o.3e-7.vp.tg.lm.DMP"
    dictd = "/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/wsj/wlist5o.dic"
    wavfile = sys.argv[1]
    recognised = decodeSpeech(hmdir,lmd,dictd,wavfile)

    print "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
    print recognised
    print "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
```

Comment: What is your question? You need to make it very clear so people can help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to fix your post. When posting, please use the preview function to see if your formatting worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file has wrong format. Make sure it is 16khz 16bit mono PCM file.

Also, you are using old pocketsphinx. Make sure you use http://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python

Comment: Thanks for the help :)